# Reduce number of Import packages in an OSGi Bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

Inside a OSGi bundle I'm trying to remove the `*;resolution=optional` and specify the specific imports.
When I check at the run time imports are like follows

```
org.apache.catalina.valves; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.util; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.session; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.realm; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.core; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.connector; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.authenticator; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina; version="8.0.20",
org.apache.catalina.tribes; version="0.0.0"<unwired><optional>
org.apache.catalina.tribes.group; version="0.0.0"<unwired><optional>
org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors; version="0.0.0"<unwired><optional>
org.apache.catalina.tribes.io; version="0.0.0"<unwired><optional>
org.apache.catalina.tribes.tipis; version="0.0.0"version="0.0.0"<unwired><optional>
```

Can I reduce this like this?

```
<Import-Package>
    org.apache.catalina.*;version="8.0.20",
    org.apache.catalina.tribes.*;resolution:=optional,
</Import-Package>
```

Is this a good practice?

When I build the jar with later configuration, still in the MANIFEST file it shows resolution=optional next to the packages

Edited

Dependency section

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to do. These packages are dependencies of the code inside your bundle. If you don't want the dependencies, then don't use those packages...

Comment: @NeilBartlett I'm creating an OSGi bundle from the mentioned dependency and exporting some of its packages

Comment: I see... so, what's the problem?

Comment: After creating the bundle when in check the MANIFEST it still uses resolution:=optional with the versions

Comment: Right, that's consistent with the snippet you have posted from your maven instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use * in the Manifest but you can use the maven-bundle-plugin and in its configurations * is possible.

In maven-bundle-plugin you normally do not have to specify your imports by hand at all. The plugin scans for used packages and configures the import package statements including standard version ranges. If your maven dependency is optional it will also use the optional flag.

Comment: I'm using maven-bundle plugin. I have edit my question

Comment: Can you also show the relevant maven dependencies in your pom?

Comment: Try to make your maven dependency non optional. Not sure if this is what you want on the maven side but it may help for the manifest.

Comment: Yeah then it works. And it seems that  org.apache.catalina.*;version="8.0.20", get precedence and therefore resolution=optional in org.apache.catalina.tribes get skipped. Seems I have to define packages one by one